# Viewbag value not show in ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using C# and ASP.NET MVC and try to pass data from the controller to the view. When I debug data show in viewbag but not show in view. The error is **undefined**. I don't know why this code shows an error.

This is the screenshot:

[Screenshot of Debug Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoGAY.jpg)

C# code:

```
public JsonResult mselectCOACodes(string gl_code)
{
    ViewBag.mainCode = gl_code.Substring(0, 2) + "-00-00-0000";

    if (ViewBag.mainCode != "")
    {
        ViewBag.mainDesc = _ICOA.mSelectChartofAccount(ViewBag.mainCode);
    }

    return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#txtvglcode").change(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/ChartofAccount/mselectCOACodes",
                data: {
                    gl_code: $("#txtvglcode").val() 
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
              
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

View

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <b>Main Code</b>
            <div class="form-line">
                <input type="text" id="txtglmainCode" 
                       value="@ViewBag.mainCode" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <b>Description</b>
            <div class="form-line">
                <input type="text" id="txtmainDescription" 
                       value="@ViewBag.mainDesc" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The view is not used at all, since the controller returns `Json()`... have a look at the result in the browser Network dev tool tab.

Comment: You're returning JSON, not a view.  And it's in an ajax request.  Your first view is already rendered.  You're getting confused which request is doing what.

Comment: You could make a partial view that updates via Ajax when code is changed and return partial view result in your controller method.

Comment: Off topic pic: Place a `!` bevore your link. Then the linked image is displayed intext (`![Screenshot of Debug Result](https://...)`)

Comment: can you give me sample @derloopkat

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, don't use `@ViewBag` to store the input value, because you cannot access its value inside your C# code.
Here is C# code:

```
public JsonResult mselectCOACodes(string gl_code)
{
    string mainCode = gl_code.Substring(0, 2) + "-00-00-0000";

    if (mainCode != "")
    {
       string mainDesc = _ICOA.mSelectChartofAccount(ViewBag.mainCode);
    }

    return Json(mainDesc, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#txtvglcode").change(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/ChartofAccount/mselectCOACodes",
                data: {
                    gl_code: $("#txtvglcode").val() 
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (mainDesc) {
                    $("#txtmainDescription").val(mainDesc);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <b>Main Code</b>
            <div class="form-line">
                <input type="text" id="txtglmainCode" 
                       value="" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <b>Description</b>
            <div class="form-line">
                <input type="text" id="txtmainDescription" 
                       value="" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```